# How to package Qt5 application with snapcraft

Tags: qt, qml, qmake, snapcraft

I'm trying to create snap package of a [Qt/QML application](https://github.com/Tenpeter/snap), the application is packaged well, when I try to run it I get `/snap/swipe-app/x2/bin/qt5-launch: 74: exec: application: not found` error.

here's my snapcraft.yaml file

```
name: swipe-app # you probably want to 'snapcraft register <name>'
version: '0.1' # just for humans, typically '1.2+git' or '1.3.2'
summary: Single-line elevator pitch for your amazing snap # 79 char long summary
description: description
grade: devel # must be 'stable' to release into candidate/stable channels
confinement: strict # use 'strict' once you have the right plugs and slots

apps:
  swipe-app:
    command: qt5-launch application
    plugs:
      - unity7
      - home

parts:
  application:
     # See 'snapcraft plugins'
    plugin: qmake
    project-files: ["snap.pro"]
    source: .
    build-packages:
      - qtbase5-dev
    stage-packages:
      # Here for the plugins-- they're not linked in automatically.
      - libqt5gui5
           after: [qt5conf] # A wiki part
```

Comment: In my experience, you need more than just one Qt library when you are running.  Have you tried running 'ldd' on the executable?

Answer (score 0):

As you have told the launch script that your program is called `application` then it will try to execute `application` from the current working directory when you run your snap. There are two things to note here:

The working directory is preserved from the terminal *outside* the snap context. For example if you are in your home directory `/home/your-user` then the working directory for `swipe-app` will also be `/home/your-user`.

As the working directory above is your home directory then commands without any anchor, such as `application`, will try to execute in your home directory. So in your example the launch script will attempt to run the command equivalent of `/home/your-user/application`.

You can fix this by either ensuring that the launch script executes a `cd` to change the working directory, e.g. `cd $SNAP`; or anchor your command by adding an achor, e.g. `command: qt5-launch $SNAP/application`.

Another thing you might need to check is that your `qmake` build actually outputs a binary called `application`. If you have not set `TARGET=` in your `snap.pro` project file then the binary will default to being called `snap`, **not** `application`. The line should read `TARGET=application` to make a binary called `application`: (ref: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#target).